# How to select/delete anything in quotes in an R string? How to delete numbers in a character column?

Tags: r, single-quotes

I have a column of strings, an example of it is below :

'abc'

'def'

123

456

ghi

jkl

mno23

I want to delete the values which have quotes and the numbers so I want my final data to look like

ghi

jkl

mno23

Any help how to do this in R?

Comment: can you show the `dput` of the example to get the structure correctly.  May be you need `subset(df1, !grepl("'", col1))`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `grepl` (or `grep`) from `base R`

```
subset(df1, !grepl("'", col1))
```

Or with `grep`

```
df1[grep("'", df1$col1, invert = TRUE),]
```

---

If we need to remove both numbers only string and `'`

```
subset(df1, grepl('^[A-Za-z]+$', col1))
```

Or change the previous condition to check if there is `'` or (`|`) one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the string and negate (`!`) the logical vector derived from `grepl`

```
subset(df1, !grepl("'|^[0-9]+$", col1))
#   col1
#5  ghi
#6  jkl
```

Or if it is any digit

```
subset(df1, !grepl("'|[0-9]", col1))
#   col1
#5  ghi
#6  jkl
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("'abc'", "'def'", 123, 456, "ghi", "jkl"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can I do the same for number? I have some numbers too in this column?

Comment: @Stats_Uwash you want to remove all the numbers or any number i.e. `41, '4a', 'aaa4'` should all these removed along with `'`

Comment: So with your code I have removed the things with quotes, I also have numbers in this column, like 

ghi

123

jkl

I want to remove the 123 part.

Comment: @Stats_Uwash can you please update your post by editing and the expected output

Comment: @Stats_Uwash I updated the post with multiple cases.  Hopefully, one of them should work for you

Comment: I however don't want to remove an '4a', but your last piece of code is doing that too, anyway around this?

Comment: `subset(df1, !grepl("'|^[0-9]+$", col1))` should work for trhat